# Plot each row of data frame as separate graph in R

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a data frame in this format:

```
row.names 100 50 25 0
metabolite1 113417.2998 62594.7067  39460.7705  1.223243e+02
metabolite2 3494058.7972 2046871.7446 1261278.2476 6.422864e+03
```

The columns refer to the concentrations of quality controls (%): 100, 50, 25, 0.

Currently to plot a single graph I am extracting the data into a new data frame and plotting it like this:

```
metabolite1 <- data.frame(Numbers = c(100,50,25,0), Signal = c(113417.2998,62594.7067,39460.7705,122.3243)) 
# Extract coefficient of variance for line of best fit
Coef <- coef(lm(Signal ~ Numbers, data = metabolite1))
# plot data
ggplot(metabolite1, aes(x = Numbers, y = Signal)) +
  geom_point() + 
  xlim(0,100) +
  geom_abline(intercept = Coef[1], slope = Coef[2])
```

This is extremely inefficient and I am trying to find a better way to plot separate scatter plots for each row rather than creating separate data frames. What would be a better way to do this? I have 160 metabolites I need to produce graphs for. I have attempted the melt the data frame into the format:

```
Name variable value
metabolite1 100 113417.2998
metabolite2 100 3494058.7972
metabolite1 50 62594.7067
metabolite2 50 2046871.7446
metabolite1 25 39460.7705
metabolite2 25 1261278.2476
metabolite1 0 1.223243e+02
metabolite2 0 6.422864e+03
```

and then use ggplot and faceting to plot the data

```
ggplot(data = df, aes(x = variable, y = value)) +
geom_point() + facet_grid(~ Name)
```

but the plots produced all have the same y axis scale which is not appropriate for the data I am working with. I'm assuming because of this I cannot use faceting to produce the plots.

EDIT: I do not know how to add separate lines of best fit to each plot without using geom_smooth, which I do not wish to do.

Comment: You can set the `scales` argument in `facet_grid` to `free_y` to allow the y-axis scales to vary across facets.

Comment: I'm not sure how I can add line of best fits for each individual plot for this method, as `geom_smooth` lines of best fit are not the same as `lm`.

Comment: `geom_smooth` has a `method` argument, which you can set to `lm`.

Comment: I know, however when I have tested both methods before, the lines of best fit produced are not the same

Comment: you can use `library(MASS)` and then try the `method="rlm"` argument (robust lm -> slopes less  sensitive to outliers)

Comment: I would be very surprised if that were the case... if you can reproduce this behavior (different `lm` lines) you should append your code/output to this question or open a new question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're on the right track with your method of melting and faceting:

```
ggplot(data = df, aes(x = variable, y = value)) +
  geom_point() + 
  geom_smooth(method = "lm", se = FALSE, lwd = .5, col = "black") +
  facet_wrap(~ Name, scales = "free_y")
```

[image]

This yields similar plots as those you get from running `ggplot` on subsets:

```
out <- lapply(list(metabolite1, metabolite2), function(d) {
  Coef <- coef(lm(Signal ~ Numbers, data = d))
  # plot data
  p <- ggplot(d, aes(x = Numbers, y = Signal)) +
    geom_point() + 
    xlim(0,100) +
    geom_abline(intercept = Coef[1], slope = Coef[2]) 
})
gridExtra::grid.arrange(out[[1]], out[[2]], nrow = 1)
```

[image]